# Javascript - validation, numbers only

Tags: javascript, validation, numbers

I'm trying to get my login form to only validate if only numbers were inputted. I can it to work if the input is only digits, but when i type any characters after a number, it will still validate etc. 12akf will work. 1am will work. How can i get past this?

Part of the Login

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label for="firstname">Age: </label>
    <input name="num" type="text" id="username" size="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="return validateForm()">

function validateForm()
{

    var z = document.forms["myForm"]["num"].value;
    if(!z.match(/^\d+/))
        {
        alert("Please only enter numeric characters only for your Age! (Allowed input:0-9)")
        }
}
```

Comment: You are better to use *test*, which returns a boolean: `if (/\D/.test(z)) {/* non-digit found */}`.

Comment: Also better to put the listener on the form as it can be submitted without pressing the submit button.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Match against `/^\d+$/`.  `$` means "end of line", so any non-digit characters after the initial run of digits will cause the match to fail.

**Edit:**

RobG wisely suggests the more succinct `/\D/.test(z)`. This operation tests the inverse of what you want. It returns `true` if the input has *any* non-numeric characters.

Simply omit the negating `!`  and use `if(/\D/.test(z))`.

Comment: this doesn't work. Now it just accepts the validation even if its not digits. i changed it to : if(!z.match(/^\d+$/.$))

Comment: Wait, are you not getting `z.match(/^\d+$/)` to work?  It works fine for me.  The final `.$` in the code from your comment does nothing -- that period and dollar sign are outside the regex pattern and are interpreted as regex modifier characters (like `g` for global or `i` for case-insensitive).

Comment: @apsillers—consider instead `/\D/.test(z)`, shorter and simpler.

Comment: You don't need a ! if using /\d/.test(z)

Comment: @JillAndMr That tests for the presence of *any* numbers, but the question asks to test if a string is *only* numbers. (For example, your test would match`hello5` but that is not a numbers-only string.)

Answer (score 29):

here is how to validate the input to only accept numbers this will accept numbers like 123123123.41212313

```
<input type="text" 
onkeypress="if ( isNaN(this.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"
/>
```

and this will not accept entering the dot (.), so it will only accept integers

```
<input type="text" 
onkeypress="if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )) return false;"
/>
```

this way you will not permit the user to input anything but numbers

Comment: on pasting text this is not validating

Comment: You can validate on another even such submitting form

Answer (score 17):

This one worked for me :

```
function validateForm(){

  var z = document.forms["myForm"]["num"].value;

  if(!/^[0-9]+$/.test(z)){
    alert("Please only enter numeric characters only for your Age! (Allowed input:0-9)")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Late answer,but may be this will help someone

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Use will be like

```
nn=document.forms["myForm"]["num"].value;

ans=isNumber(nn);

if(ans)
{
    //only numbers
}
```

This ans was found from here with huge vote

[Validate numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Answer (score 9):

```js
function validateNumber(e) {
            const pattern = /^[0-9]$/;

            return pattern.test(e.key )
        }
```

```html
 
 <input name="username" id="username" onkeypress="return validateNumber(event)">
```

This approach doesn't lock numlock numbers, arrows, home, end buttons and etc

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution.

Thanks to my partner that gave me this answer.

You can set an **onkeypress** event on the **input** textbox like this:

`onkeypress="validate(event)"`

and then use regular expressions like this:

```
function validate(evt){
     evt.value = evt.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
}
```

It will scan and remove any letter or sign different from number in the field.

Comment: Does that still work when text is pasted in to an input textbox?

Comment: .replace(/[^0-9]/g,"") is the best and simplest solution I've found. I needed even commas and currency dot so .replace(/[^0-9,.]/g,"") was an exact match for me.

Answer (score 3):

> No need for the long code for number input restriction just try this code.
>
> It also accepts valid int & float both values.

### Javascript Approach

```js
onload =function(){ 
  var ele = document.querySelectorAll('.number-only')[0];
  ele.onkeypress = function(e) {
     if(isNaN(this.value+""+String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)))
        return false;
  }
  ele.onpaste = function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Input box that accepts only valid int and float values.</p>
<input class="number-only" type=text />
```

### jQuery Approach

```js
$(function(){

  $('.number-only').keypress(function(e) {
 if(isNaN(this.value+""+String.fromCharCode(e.charCode))) return false;
  })
  .on("cut copy paste",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Input box that accepts only valid int and float values.</p>
<input class="number-only" type=text />
```

The above answers are for most common use case - validating input as a number.

> But to allow few special cases like
>   negative numbers & showing the invalid keystrokes to user before
>   removing it, so below is the code snippet for such special use cases.

```js
$(function(){
      
  $('.number-only').keyup(function(e) {
        if(this.value!='-')
          while(isNaN(this.value))
            this.value = this.value.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/[\D]/i,'')
                                   .split('').reverse().join('');
    })
    .on("cut copy paste",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Input box that accepts only valid int and float values.</p>
<input class="number-only" type=text />
```

Comment: Hey @vinayakj i have taken the reference of this answer for StackOverflow in spanish, btw excellent answer! http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/34744/95

Comment: Thanks @Elenasys.. sure.. thanks for spreading the answer to spanish audience.

Answer (score 2):

Using the form you already have:

```
var input = document.querySelector('form[name=myForm] #username');

input.onkeyup = function() {
    var patterns = /[^0-9]/g;
    var caretPos = this.selectionStart;

    this.value = input.value.replace(patterns, '');
    this.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
}
```

This will delete all non-digits after the key is released.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are great, but why not just make sure it's a number before trying to do something with it?

```
function addemup() {
var n1 = document.getElementById("num1");
var n2 = document.getElementById("num2");
sum = Number(n1.value) + Number(n2.value);
    if(Number(sum)) {
        alert(sum);
        } else {
            alert("Numbers only, please!");
        };
    };
```

Comment: this requires more computation than regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
function ValidateNumberOnly()
{
if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)) 
{
   event.returnValue = false;
}
}
```

this function will allow only numbers in the textfield.

Comment: but cannot enter decimal using this!

Answer (score 2):

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("number-validation"); //use the CLASS in your input field.
for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
   elem[i].addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
      var keys = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 0];
      var validIndex = keys.indexOf(event.charCode);
      if(validIndex == -1){
         event.preventDefault();
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we do not accept long structure programming we will add everytime shot code see below answer.

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" >
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid symbols like "." "," "+" "-". I tried it and it works fine.

```js
$('#example').keypress(function (evt) {            
  if (evt != null && evt.originalEvent != null && /\D/.test(evt.originalEvent.key)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  }      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="example" id="example">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using React, just do:

```js
<input
  value={this.state.input}
  placeholder="Enter a number"
  onChange={e => this.setState({ input: e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') })}
/>
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
class Demo extends React.Component {
    state = {
      input: '',
    }
    
    onChange = e => {
      let input = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
      this.setState({ input });
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input
              value={this.state.input}
              placeholder="Enter a number"
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
            <br />
            <h1>{this.state.input}</h1>
           </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: Would have been great if I can use it for decimals too. Not allowing me to add "."

Answer (score 0):

// I use this jquery it works perfect, just add class nosonly to any textbox  that should be numbers only:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $(".nosonly").keydown(function (event) {
           // Allow only backspace and delete
           if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
               // let it happen, don't do anything
           }
           else {
               // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
               if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
              alert("Only Numbers Allowed"),event.preventDefault();
               }
           }
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Number validation in react. User can only write 0 to 9 as input value.

```
const validateNumber = (evt) => {
 const pattern = /^[0-9]$/;
 return !pattern.test(evt.key) && evt.preventDefault();
}

<input type="text" name="name" onKeyPress={(evt) => validateNumber(evt)} />
```