# TextBox validation Issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a textbox and its javascript function declared as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onKeyUp="javascript:Count(this);" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
```

> 

```
                           function Count(text) {
                               //asp.net textarea maxlength doesnt work; do it by hand
                               var maxlength = 4; //set your value here (or add a parm and pass it in)
                               var object = document.getElementById(text.id)  //get your object
                               if (object.value.length > maxlength) {
                                   object.focus(); //set focus to prevent jumping
                                   object.value = text.value.substring(0, maxlength); //truncate the value
                                   object.scrollTop = object.scrollHeight; //scroll to the end to prevent jumping
                                   return false;
                               }
                               return true;
                           }
```

I have also set the TextMode property of TextBox to Number, but i can still enter the Alphabet "e/E" and while entering this particular alphabet my javascript function is also not called. How should i solve this problem.

Comment: you have given wrong event name. its onkeyup not onKeyUp...

Comment: The function is called normally on this event name also..

Comment: you don't want to enter E/e right???

Comment: may be duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713749/javascript-validation-numbers-only

Comment: Yes i don't want "E" to be entered in the textbox...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use multiple data types for validating the input. And you can just use the `MaxLength` attribute to limit the characters to 4.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" onkeyup="checkString(this, 'INT')" MaxLength="4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkString(inputID, inputType) {
        if (inputID.value != "") {
            if (inputType == "NUMERIC") {
                validChars = "0-9,.";
            } else if (inputType == "INT") {
                validChars = "0-9";
            } else if (inputType == "HASHTAG") {
                validChars = "a-z0-9-_#";
            } else if (inputType == "ALPHA") {
                validChars = "a-z";
            } else {
                validChars = "a-z0-9";
            }

            var regexp = new RegExp("[" + validChars + "]+", "ig");
            var matches = inputID.value.match(regexp);

            if (matches == null) {
                inputID.value = "";
            } else if (matches.length != 0) {
                inputID.value = matches.join("");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```