# Number.isNaN not working for input validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, numbers

I have a problem.

I want to show an alert saying "you have a problem" when the user enters something into the `input` that is not a number.

```js
function function1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  if (Number.isNaN(x)) {
    alert("you have a problem");
  }

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Mohsen Yeganeh</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="number1">
  <button type="submit" onclick="function1()">click me</button>


</body>

</html>
```

It is not working, however. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713749/javascript-validation-numbers-only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - validation, numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713749/javascript-validation-numbers-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) checks whether the argument is [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), **not** whether or not it is a number.

```js
Number.isNaN(NaN) // true
Number.isNaN("Hello World!") // false, "Hello World!" != NaN
```

You should be using [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead, which checks whether the argument is a number or not:

```js
function function1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("you have a problem");
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Mohsen Yeganeh</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="number1">
  <button type="submit" onclick="function1()">click me</button>


</body>

</html>
```